# How to draw frustum in opengl

Tags: opengl, 3d, projection

I want to draw a frustum using `GL_LINE_STRIP`. What will be my coordinates for these frustum vertices? I have model view and projection matrices. Is it possible to calculate coordinates in shader itself using these matrices?

Comment: In what space do you want to draw your frustum? Is this for some kind of overview/rader?

Comment: @derhass world space.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want the world space coordinates for the frustum corners, all you need to do is project the 8 corner points from NDC space (which is going from -1 to 1 in every dimension, so the corner points are easy to enumerate) back to world space. But do not forget that you have to divide by `w`:

```
c_world = inverse(projection * view) * vec4(c_ncd, 1);
c_world = c_world*1.0/c_world.w;
```

While I wrote this in GLSL syntax, this is meant as pseudocode only. You *can* do it in the shader, but that means that this has to be calculated many times (depending on which shader stage you put this into). It is typically much faster to at least pre-calculate that inverted matrix on the CPU.

Comment: can you please explain you answer.

Comment: @debonair: The corners of your viewing volume in NDC space (which is `vec4 (clip_space.xyz / clip_space.w, 1.0 / clip_space.w)`) are all some combination of **-1** and **1**. For 3 dimensions, you have 2^3 = 8 combinations of **-1** and **1** you need to use to find all the corners in NDC. Once you have that, multiply it by your inverse projection matrix to get to clip-space and your inverse view matrix to get to world-space (that can be combined into a single step as derhass demonstrated). Division by `w` is what produces the frustum shape, by the way - if you leave that out you have a cube.

Comment: @debonair: I made a typo in that comment, but the idea is the same... the inverse projection matrix will take you to view-space (from clip-space). You are actually going to skip over that coordinate space, so it does not really matter, but I might as well correct that :P